Is there a way to upload a color look-up table to Unity to use on NReal glasses?
I am trying to create three different lenses/filters for a pair of NReal glasses using 3 color look-up tables that I have. I previously used Snapchat's AR Lens Studio and was hoping there was a way to transfer one to the other, but it looks like Snapchat's AR has to be linked to Snapchat in one way or another.
I was going to use a documentation page that referred to a standard assets package ...but that seems to be out of date.
I found another documentation that seems up to date, but has little to no information on how to actually do it. (https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.1/manual/Color-Grading.html)
This is my first time developing a project like this on Unity, so bear with me if I'm missing something basic. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

well the documentation you linked is from the Post-Processing Package you would have to install and setup first

@derHugo I have since downloaded the post-processing package - still struggling with how to actually implement what I want to do on it though.

are you using URP or HRDP by any chance? There post-processing works slightly different .. see https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.1/manual/Post-Processing-Channel-Mixer.html / https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@11.0/manual/Post-Processing-Channel-Mixer.html .. this would be the one to go with for your use case I guess
